# Zsh autocomplete function with sed

Tags: bash, zsh, tmux, sed, autocomplete

I'm struggling to write an ZSH autocomplete function. My goal is to autocomplete `ta`'s and `tk`'s first argument with the projects listed in `tmux list-sessions` and `tmuxinator list`.

Here's what I have so far:

`tmux list-sessions` outputs data that looks like this:

```
dotfiles: 1 windows (created Tue Apr 15 21:54:51 2014) [123x48]
goodbye: 1 windows (created Tue Apr 15 21:51:34 2014) [123x48]
hello: 1 windows (created Tue Apr 15 21:42:03 2014) [123x48]
```

`tmuxinator list` outputs:

```
tmuxinator projects:
dotfiles           landonschropp.com
```

Here's my attempt:

```
tmux-list-sessions-autofill() {

  # get the tmux and tmuxinator sessions
  TMUX_SESSIONS=$( tmux list-sessions | cut -d: -f1 )
  TMUXINATOR_SESSIONS=$( tmuxinator list | tail -n +2 | gsed -e 's/\s\+/\n/g' )

  # remove duplicates
  SESSIONS=$( echo "$TMUX_SESSIONS\n$TMUXINATOR_SESSIONS" | sort | uniq )

  # set the autocomplete values
  reply=( $(echo $SESSIONS) )
}

compctl -K tmux-list-sessions-autofill ta
compctl -K tmux-list-sessions-autofill tk
```

- `tmux list-sessions | cut -d: -f1` removes everything but the project names.
- `tmuxinator list | tail -n +2 | gsed -e 's/\s\+/\n/g'` removes the first line and replaces the whitespace with newlines.
- `echo "$TMUX_SESSIONS\n$TMUXINATOR_SESSIONS" | sort | uniq` removes duplicate lines.
- I'm using `gsed` because I'm on OS X and `sed` is a bit screwy.

My function works, but it's *really* slow. I'm a shell scripting novice, so I'm sure there's a more efficient way to accomplish this. Where is my bottleneck and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you rule out that the two commands `tmux list-sessions` and `tmuxinator list` cause the delay? I'd be interested in `time tmuxinator list`, `time tmuxinator list | tail -n +2` and `time tmuxinator list | tail -n +2 | gsed -e 's/\s\+/\n/g'`. With analogue command you might track down if the delay is caused by one command or if it results only in total.

Comment: Oh, wow, I didn't know about the time command. That's pretty cool. I ran each command 5 times and averaged the result. `time tmux list-sessions` took 0.05s by `time tmuxinator list` took 0.716s. `time tmuxinator list | tail -n +2` and `time tmuxinator list | tail -n +2 | gsed -e 's/\s\+/\n/g'` didn't add a significant delay. I guess I'll open an issue in tmuxinator for this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad, you found the bottleneck. I wrote an answer which uses only builtin zsh capabilities to parse the session lists. You want to use the powers of zsh, don't you?! `;)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To track down the delay you can use the builtin command `time` which can list the contributions of all commands in a pipe:

   ```
   zsh% time sleep 2 | date | sleep 1
   sleep 2  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 2.003 total
   date  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 0.004 total
   sleep 1  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 1.004 total
   ```
2. While (according to you comment) it's the external command `tmuxinator list`  which causes the noticable delay, you can neverthelesss optimize your completion function. You used a lot of external commands (`sed`, `cut`, ...) to parse the output. Here I'll show one approach that uses only zsh's builtin capabilities.

   ```
   tmux-list-sessions-autofill() {
     local -aU SESSIONS
     SESSIONS=("${(@)${(f)$(tmux list-sessions)}/:*/}")
     SESSIONS+=("${(@)${(f)$(tmuxinator list-sessions)}[2,-1]/[ $'\t']*/}")
     reply=(${(i)SESSIONS})
   }
   ```

   This might look complicated at the first glance, but once you get used to it, the parameter expansion of zsh is *very* powerful. From top to bottom:

   - `local -aU` declares a local parameter `SESSIONS`, which is an array (`a`) and `U`  *keeps array values unique*. <sup>+</sup>
   - first, get the sessions from `tmux list-sessions`, explained from inside to outside:

     - `$(tmux list-sessions)` gets the output of the external command
     - `${(f)$(tmux list-sessions)}` splits the result at `\n`
     - `${(@)${(f)$(tmux list-sessions)}/:*/}` operates on every array element (`(@)`) and does a search & replace `/from/to`, i.e. removing everthing after and including the first colon.
     - Now, `$SESSIONS` will include `(dotfiles goodbye hello)`. Use `print -l $SESSIONS`  to print every array element on a single line.
   - next, nearly the same procedure for `tmuxinator list`, with these additions:

     - use only the second to the last element (`[2,-1]`)
     - erase everything after (and including) a `space` or `tab` (`$'\t'`) character
     - add these elements (`+=`) to the `SESSIONS` array
   - finally, return the `SESSIONS` array sorted case-insensitive `(i)`

All these expansions use the longer, general form of `${parameter}` instead of the shorthand notation `$parameter`. See `man zshexpn` for a much better explanation of the syntax and the socalled *Parameter Expansion Flags* (like `(f)`).

---

<sup>+</sup> According to [Bart Schaefer](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users//1998/msg00489.html) the `U` flag is not necessary, because *the completion code makes its internal list of completions unique,
so it doesn't really help to remove the redundant entries from arrays
in advance when using them only for completion.*

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you so much for taking the time to write all of that. It's really helpful.

Comment: @LandonSchropp Hey, thanks a lot for the extra bounty `:)` It wasn't necessary, though -- I was glad that I could give you some clues.

Comment: It might not have been necessary, but I felt like you went out of your way to help and I wanted to say thanks. :)

Answer (score -1):

Here's another alternative :)

```
tmux-list-sessions-autofill() {
    reply=( `tmux list-sessions | sed "s/:.*//g"` );
}
```

===== EDIT =====

So I reformulate my answer here, in reponse to @NetworkKingPin 's comment.

In the original post of @LandonSchropp, you should just change your `tmux-list-sessions-autofill()` function to this:

```
tmux-list-sessions-autofill() {
    reply=( `tmux list-sessions -F '#{session_name}'` ); 
}
```

Notice that in my original post, I was using `sed` to delete any other information besides the session names.
But this time I'm using an `-F` argument which tells `tmux` to **only** print the session names, and skip any other information.

This works great for me.
Hope this is clear enough.

Comment: Explaining your Alternative would be better for the Person who asked the Question that way they understand it.